# Laravel and Spatie Permissions plugin update not working

Tags: laravel, roles, user-roles, laravel-permission, laravel-9

I've performed a long-overdue update on a Laravel project from v5.7 (with Spatie Permissions 2.21) to v9 with Spatie 5.5.0. I'm not getting any error but the `hasRole()` function no longer ever returns true for users who definitely have the role. Echoing `Auth::user()->getRoleNames()` for the user just returns an empty array. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Looking at my old commits, it seems that aside from the `composer.json` additions and database migrations, that only things I needed to do were a User model edit:

```
...
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;
...
```

And this `config/permission.php` (comments stripped):

```
<?php
return [
    'models' => [
        'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,
        'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,
    ],
    'table_names' => [
        'roles' => 'roles',
        'permissions' => 'permissions',
        'model_has_permissions' => 'model_has_permissions',
        'model_has_roles' => 'model_has_roles',
        'role_has_permissions' => 'role_has_permissions',
    ],
    'column_names' => [
        'role_pivot_key' => null, //default 'role_id',
        'permission_pivot_key' => null, //default 'permission_id',
        'model_morph_key' => 'model_id',
        'team_foreign_key' => 'team_id',
    ],
    'register_permission_check_method' => true,
    'teams' => false,
    'display_permission_in_exception' => false,
    'display_role_in_exception' => false,
    'enable_wildcard_permission' => false,
    'cache' => [
        'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),
        'key' => 'spatie.permission.cache',
        'store' => 'default',
    ],
];
```

Comment: i think the config has changed, 'cache' entry is missing from yours, perhaps it can cause issues (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/main/config/permission.php)

Comment: Thanks - looks like there are actually quite a few differences in the new config. I've updated mine accordingly though and no change unfortunately.

Comment: Run these scripts to ensure there is an actual problem:
`php artisan migrate`
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan  config:clear`
`php artisan optimize:clear`
`php artisan permission:cache-reset`

Comment: Thanks @eamirgh - most of those cleared but for `php artisan permission:cache-reset` I got `Unable to flush cache.`. No effect from the ones that did clear unfortunately.

Comment: Well now permission cache is also clearing for some reason! Still no effect though.

Comment: Personally I would setup laravel 9 project with the latest spatie/permission package. Observe the changes and compare with the old setup like database tables and columns. 

You probably need to check the guard name see if it's different, this maybe why its not picking.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas well that is how I did the upgrade - started a new Laravel 9 project with latest plugins, copied in all my controllers, views etc and imported a dump of the old database into the new database container. It looks like column names are defined in the plugin config and I've never messed with those so all default. Which file(s) would define the guard name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was connected to another problem I was having that fortunately I was trying to fix at the same time:

[Laravel upgrade broke model paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395901/laravel-upgrade-broke-model-paths/71396263#71396263)

The cause of this permissions issue was in the database but not table / field names, but actually the field contents.

In the `model_has_roles` table, the old `App\User` namespace was used (hopefully I'm using "namespace" correctly there!) and should have been `App\Models\User` in line with the new namespace. Then it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below few things i would like to try

```
$user->assignRole($this->roles)
```

Try echo below line just after assign

```
echo $user()->getRoleNames()
```

Also try fetch with relations

`Dump($user->with('roles')->get()`

It will tell you atleast roles assignment is working.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've actually found the solution and will post when I have time and select that as the answer (but congrats on the bounty anyway :-))