# Laravel upgrade broke model paths

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, namespaces

I've performed a long-overdue update on a Laravel project from v5.7 to v9 and ran into a `Target class does not exist` error. I found [this guide](https://litvinjuan.medium.com/how-to-fix-target-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel-8-f9e28b79f8b4) and used the first method to resolve the error (adding the namespace into the RoutesServiceProvider.php boot function). This resolved that error but now, everything is giving me `Class "App\Whatever" not found`.

I did notice that models are now stored in a `Models` directory within the `app` directory rather than directly in `app`, so have moved them to `Models`. I figured that might be breaking my `use App\Whatever;` lines at the top of my controllers, so I've tried `use App\Models\Whatever` and also `use app\Models\Whatever` (since the "a" is lowercase in the directory name) but no effect.

I should note I don't really have a good grasp of namespaces, MVC frameworks etc. so ELI5 etc :-)

Some of my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Thing;
use App\AnotherThing;
...
    public function thing_summary($id) // show the summary view of the thing

    {

        if(Auth::check()) {

            $thing = Thing::find($id);
...
```

Comment: There have been very significant changes since 5.7, (for example, routing syntax has changed quite a bit). Can you show us the code that throws the error?

Comment: No problem, I'll update the question. There's a lot of files though with a lot of code so let me know if I've missed something you're after.

Comment: If you moved the models, make sure you update the namespace in the models themselves.

Comment: The documentation has an [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade) from version to version, might want to read those to at least know what changed

Comment: @aynber thank you! That was the fix! If you turn that into an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 7/8/9 sticks with strict namespacing. When you move the models to a new directory, you need to update the namespace in the models themselves (if specified at all) and any file that has a `use` for the model. If the models move from `app/` to `app/models`, the namespace must be changed to `App/Models`